# Web Analytics Migration

Tags: web-analytics, adobe-analytics, webtrends

According to the requirement I have to Migrate from Webtrends Analytics to Adobe Sitecatalyst.
Can anyone help me out with the approach to this migration (or the general approach to any kind of Web Analytics  migration). How should it be done? Any kind of input (tutorials, best practices, points to remember ,etc.) would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, congrats for getting off WebTrends! I cannot express in words how much I hate WebTrends... anyways...

Normally you should have documentation of the WT implementation that details what variables were used, where they were used, what values they should have, etc. This is usually called a Functional Specification Document (FSD) or Solution Design Reference (SDR). And normally you would have documentation detailing Key Performance Indicators (KPIs) for the site that the imp doc(s) were based off.  If you have this stuff, then migrating is relatively straight forward: you just go through the docs and replace WT code for SC "equivalents".  I put that in quotes because it will not be straight apples to apples, since they are different tools, after all.

If you do not have any documentation like that laying around, then in my experience the best approach mostly pretend WT isn't there and effectively start from scratch. Go to the stakeholders (the people who actually look at and/or expect reporting) and have a powwow about what they want to track, what kind of reports they want to see, etc. and create a KPI document.  Then from there create an FSD/SDR from it, and then implement the SC code.

Then after that is done, you can go back and start working on removing the WT code.  With luck, you will have already found much of it from the SC implementation, depending on how closely the KPIs align with the original requirements implemented for WT.  Beyond that.. it will be a game of going through the WT docs to get a list of all of the variable names and methods used and doing a search on all your site(s) files for them.

**Tip:** In general you can look at the various reports in WT that are getting data as indicators of what types of WT vars are being populated and where.